# How can I use the "on_motion_detected" method on Raspberry Pi motion?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, motion, motion-detection

I have been using my Raspberry Pi 2 to do some motion detection using a USB webcam and the motion package and am incredibly frustrated.

**Can someone explain to me how the on_motion_detected method is supposed to work??????**

The idea is that when the camera detects motion, a script is executed. The script just echo's a few words for testing purposes.

The video stream works great on my local network, and I can see the motion writing the JPG and .avi files to the directory.

Even when I try to add my script to the movie start trigger, **nothing happens**.

Some examples I have tried:

- ; on_motion_detected python /home/pi/Desktop/Python/script.py
- ; on_movie_start python /home/pi/Desktop/Python/script.py
- ; on_picture_save sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/Python/script.py

I have also changed the script to different directories, speculating a permission issue. Still nothing happens. I have tried removing the ; before the methods, still nothing happens. I have tried sudo, I have tried executing as a script. Please, can someone offer some help. I have searched years and years of threads and not found an answer anywhere.

*My script is not being executed.*

This question has been asked 1000 times and nobody has answered it. I have been searching for several hours for an answer.

Here's just a few of the threads that have gone uanswered:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59091/problems-running-python-script-from-motion
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=86534&p=610482
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8273/running-script-in-motion

Comment: In past i've used a simple .sh script that append a row to a text file. It worked very well. Can you try?

Comment: Remove the ";" before at the start of the line

Answer (score 2):

Ypu have to remove ; which stands for commenting the line

; on_motion_detected python /home/pi/Desktop/Python/script.py

but

```
 on_motion_detected python /home/pi/Desktop/Python/script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use threads: threat1.conf, threat2.conf -- try to write script config to them. 
My threads:
thread1.conf

```
videodevice /dev/video0
text_left USBWebcam-1
target_dir /samba/hdd/share/motion/usb
rotate 180
width 1024
height 768
#webcam_port 9081
#on_event_start /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh
on_picture_save /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh %f
#on_motion_detected /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh
#on_area_detected /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh
#on_movie_start /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh
```

and thread2.conf:

```
text_left Foscam IP
netcam_url http://192.168.111.7:8080/video
target_dir /samba/hdd/share/motion/ip
width 1024
height 768
#on_event_start /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh
on_picture_save /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh %f
#on_motion_detected /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh
#on_area_detected /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh
#on_movie_start /bin/bash /root/scripts/tg_msg.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution but someone needs to explain how this works. Start motion as root. Add a line to /etc/rc.local 'sudo motion' reboot and most events will work if started as root, on_event_end sudo ...command or script...

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have specified the process id properly in motion.conf:

**process_id_file /var/run/motion/motion.pid**

Once you have checked that, change the following settings to arbitrarily low values e.g.

**threshold 1**

**noise_level 1**

Answer (score -1):

sudo chown motion:motion /home/pi/Desktop/Python/script.py

Comment: Remove the ";" before at the start of the line

Comment: Please describe in more detail what needs to be done, not only single shell command.